# Get the name of the current class and create a txt with that name

Tags: java, file, reflection

Especially I need the program to create a text file. The name of the text file to be the class name.
I tried this but does not work:

```
String className = this.getClass().getName();
File file = new File("C:\\" + className + ".txt");
```

Comment: What's the file name you are getting with this code? Is there any error?

Comment: What "does not work" mean? Do you get an exception, or what?

Comment: Did you tried this method => this.getClass().getCanonicalName()

Answer (score 1):

Although you are creating a `File` object, you are not telling it to create it in the filesystem.

```
String className = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

String fileName = String.format("%s.txt", className);

try {
    new File(fileName).createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Error creating new file '%s'", fileName), e);
}
```

I also think you might want to use `getSimpleName` instead of `getName`. `getName` will get you the entire package and class name (`com.package.ClassName`) whereas `getSimpleName` will just get the class name (`ClassName`)