# create a txt file and put the class name as the name of the txt

Tags: java

I'm coding a program to create a text file with the name of the class. 
I tried the following code and says: non-static variable class name cannot be referenced from a static context. I also try to make static the className string but is says again non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context.

```
String className = this.getClass().getName();

File file = new File("C:\\" + className + ".txt");

public static String logFileName = "C:\\"+className +".txt";
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the name of the current class and create a txt with that name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59454299/get-the-name-of-the-current-class-and-create-a-txt-with-that-name)

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the Classname.

String className = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

Comment: This is to get the actual name but still does not solve  my problem..tnx anyways

Answer (score 0):

Create a object of current class and then use it to get current class name and then use `createNewFile()` to create a new file at a desired location. But note that location should exist.

```
public class JavaCodes {

String getName() {
    return this.getClass().getName();
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    JavaCodes obj = new JavaCodes();
    String className = obj.getName();
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\MrGreen\\Desktop\\" + className + ".txt");
    file.createNewFile();
  }
}
```

Comment: seems good, thank you but i need to be written outside the main

Comment: @04k it is just an example, although you can write the same in any function it will work. Given it isn't static.